# Separate the creation of a command from the assignment of values

Tags: macros

I would like to know if it is possible to separate the creation of a LaTeX command from the assignment of its value. Currently, in a file, I have the creation of various commands with their default values as follows:

```
\newcommand{\university}{University name}
\newcommand{\faculty}{Faculty name}
\newcommand{\address}{Address location}
```

However, what I'm looking for is to have in a file, for example, only:

```
\newcommand{\university}{}
\newcommand{\faculty}{}
\newcommand{\address}{}
```

And in another file, to do, for example:

```
\university{University name}
\faculty{Faculty name}
\address{University address}
```

So that, from the user's perspective, the way they input data about the report is made 'transparent,' and it becomes much easier for them. I've tried to do what I mentioned, as I described, including the two files created in the main file using `\input`, but I encounter various errors such as `Undefined control sequence \university`

As I mentioned on the comments section, I found that one template available on atoner do the following: Create a file called `metadata.sty` and defines the command in the following way;

```
\newcommand{\@university}{}
\newcommand{\@faculty}{}
\newcommand{\@address}{}

\newcommand{\university}[1]{\renewcommand{\@university}{#1}}
\newcommand{\faculty}[1]{\renewcommand{\@faculty}{#1}}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\renewcommand{\@address}{#1}}
```

And in other file called `data.text` assign the value in the following way;

```
\zipcode{sfsfsfsd}
\city{Toledo}
\country{Spain}
```

Comment: every standard latex document knows command like \author or \title or \date which work like that. So yes it is possible. But you need two commands, one which stores the content and one which contains the content. \title e.g is defines as `\DeclareRobustCommand\title[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}`.

Comment: Either apply \renewcommand\university{whatEver}, or define a macro which does this. Think of \renewcommand as a setVar() function, and consider \university{} (in your case) as a getVar() function.

Comment: `\newcommand{\@university}{default university}` and `\newcommand{\university}[1]{\renewcommand{\@university{#1}}` for example, in the simplest case.

Comment: perfect I catch y'all, but is there any way to make assignation of the value without \renewcommand just I mentioned on the post like more "simpler"

Comment: I mean, just \newcommand in one hand and in the other hand just "call" the created command and assign the value, I guess I see something in one template, I'm gonna edit the post to include the example

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different problems: one is how to provide user level commands to populate macros for variable content. As everyone is saying in the comments, this requires two macros: a user macro for setting the content, and an internal macro for storing the content (which will then be used to output that content as needed.) But the second problem seems to be related to separating the user content into some sort of external configuration file. This seems like an extra complication which is not recommended. If you want to make things easier for users, don't do this.

Comment: great, now I gotta you'll guys better. thanks for all the answers provided!!